# How to bind models and form json structure?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement rest api using django rest framework. I want to form a specific JSON, having the ability to receive a nested array with a set of objects.

serializers.py

```
class CarListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # option = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'model', 'mark', 'option')
```

models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mark = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    option = models.ForeignKey('Option', related_name='option', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['model', 'mark', 'option']


class Option(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    engine = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transmission = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Expected Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "model": "Toyota",
        "mark": "Prado",
        "option": [
                   {'color': 'black', 'engine': '4.2', transmission: 'auto'},
                   {'color':'white', 'engine': '5.0', transmission: 'auto'}
                  ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "model": "Mazda",
        "mark": "CX-7",
        "option": [
                   {'color': 'white', 'engine': '3.5', transmission: 'auto'}, 
                   {'color': 'black', 'engine': '4.2', transmission: 'auto'}
                  ]
    }
]
```

Comment: you can write a ```to_representation()``` function in your serializer. and give it as you like Json Structure

Comment: thank you. Could you give a code example?

Comment: I can but before that, I don't understand your given example. you have a ForeignKey relation to Option but in json example you are showing two options for each car? did you mearn ```ManyToMany``` instead of ```Foreign Key```?

Comment: Perhaps I made a mistake somewhere in the Foreign Key assignment. I need to get for each machine an option with a set of elements